Excluding Sundays from Consecutive Days Analysis in R (dplyr): Finding Out-of-Stock Items and Merging Datasets
Working on a dataset called allorders, itemgreen, and medicines. after leftjoin these datasets based on branch and itemcode, I have to see the quantity which is out_of_stock in the last seven days. I have arranged this data based on branch and itemcode. But there is Sunday in between. How to deal with this the Sunday as there is no data on Sunday. last date is 08/04/2024. here is code that I have done:
library(dplyr)

allorders <-  read.csv("allorders.csv")
items_ecogreen <-  read.csv("items_ecogreen.csv")
medicines <-  read.csv("medicines.csv")

result <-  left_join(allorders, items_ecogreen, by = c("itemcode" = "c_item_code"))

final_result <-  left_join(result, medicines, by = c("itemcode"="pos_item_code"))

View(final_result)

final_result$date <-  as.Date(final_result$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

today <- max(final_result$date)
last_7_days <- today - 7 

recent_data <-  final_result %>%
  filter(date >=  max(final_result$date) - 7)

out_of_stock <- filter(recent_data, qty > 0)

out_of_stock_recent <- filter(out_of_stock, date >= last_7_days)

out_of_stock_summary <- out_of_stock_recent %>%
  group_by(branch, itemcode, date, c_item_name, c_cat_code, c_mfac_name) %>%
  summarise(out_of_stock = sum(qty))

colnames(out_of_stock_summary)

final_data <- out_of_stock_summary[, c(1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5)]

View(final_data)

Q1) How to deal with the Sunday?
NEXT PART:
now I have three more datasets named stock_rank_rank, stock_rank_pharma, and stock_rank_rx which are the top 200 ranks of combination branch and itemcode. I have merged each of the datasets with the final data and have to find the which combination of branch and itemcode is out_of_stock for last three or more consecutive days are out_of_stock. Then I have join these 3 dataset. for this below is the code I have done:
stock_rank_rank <- read.csv("stock_rank_rank.csv")
View(stock_rank_rank)

merged_rank <-  left_join(final_data, stock_rank_rank, by = c( "branch" = "branch" , "itemcode" = "c_item_code"))
View(merged_rank)

merged_rank <- merged_rank %>%
  filter(!is.na(rank))

View(merged_rank)

merged_rank$date <- as.Date(merged_rank$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

last_date <- max(merged_rank$date)

last_3_days <- last_date - 3

filtered_merged_rank <- merged_rank %>%
  filter(date >= last_3_days)

View(filtered_merged_rank)

write.csv(filtered_merged_rank, file = "filtered_merged_rank.csv")


stock_rank_pharma <- read.csv("stock_rank_pharma.csv")
View(stock_rank_pharma)

merged_pharma <-  left_join(final_data, stock_rank_pharma, by = c( "branch" = "branch" , "itemcode" = "c_item_code"), relationship = "many-to-many")
View(merged_pharma)

merged_pharma <- merged_pharma %>%
  filter(!is.na(pharma_rank))

View(merged_pharma)

merged_pharma$date <- as.Date(merged_pharma$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

last_date <- max(merged_pharma$date)

last_3_days <- last_date - 3

filtered_merged_pharma <- merged_pharma %>%
  filter(date >= last_3_days)

View(filtered_merged_pharma)

write.csv(filtered_merged_pharma, file = "filtered_merged_pharma.csv")


stock_rank_rx <- read.csv("stock_rank_rx.csv")

View(stock_rank_rx)

merged_rx <-  left_join(final_data, stock_rank_rx, by = c( "branch" = "branch" , "itemcode" = "c_item_code"), relationship = "many-to-many")
View(merged_rx)

merged_rx <- merged_rx %>%
  filter(!is.na(rx_rank))

View(merged_rx)

merged_rx$date <- as.Date(merged_rx$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

last_date <- max(merged_rx$date)

last_3_days <- last_date - 3

filtered_merged_rx <- merged_rx %>%
  filter(date >= last_3_days)

View(filtered_merged_rx)

write.csv(filtered_merged_rx, file = "filtered_merged_rx.csv")

main_file <- rbind(filtered_merged_rank, filtered_merged_pharma, filtered_merged_rx)
View(main_file)

main_file <- main_file %>%
  distinct(branch, itemcode, date, out_of_stock, .keep_all = TRUE)
View(main_file)

write.csv(main_file, file = "main_file.csv")

Q2) the problem I have got is in the filtered_merged_rank,  filtered_merged_pharma, filtered_merged_rx, I got the result of only 05/04/2024 result and 5th and 6th April data also. I need result for last three consecutive date exclude sunday that is 07/04/2024.
Please help me with that.

Can you provide some sample data?
